# Generalized 4-variable Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

The diophantine equation $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2 = 2(a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4)$, which it's the case of Descartes' circle theorem where all curvature are integer perfect squares, was cleverly solved by Euler noticing some pythagorean triples. Generalising, if instead of 2 there was another number, is it still possible to use some similar trick? In particular, it's possible to find a parametrization to the primitive integer solutions of $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2 = 3(a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4)$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give us the page number & book reference where you saw your equation dealth with by Euler. Also a numerical solution if you have one will be benificial. In literature there is mention of three variables (a,b,c) instead of four variables(a,b,c,d) as mentioned by you. For example, for the Pythagorean triple (3,4,5) an example is: (3^4+4^4+5^4)^2=2(3^8+4^8+5^8). There is also a numerical solution for (a^2-b^2+c^2)^2= (a^4+b^4+c^4), where (a,b,c)=(15,12,20).

Comment: @David In wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Descartes'_Circle_Theorem is mentioned the Euler's trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euler found that the equation,

$$(v^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 = 2(v^4 + x^4 + y^4 + z^4)\tag1$$

is equivalent to any three of the Pythagorean triples,

$$(2v x)^2 + (2y z)^2 = (v^2 + x^2 - y^2 - z^2)^2\\
 (2v y)^2 + (2x z)^2 = (v^2 - x^2 + y^2 - z^2)^2\\
 (2v z)^2 + (2x y)^2 = (v^2 - x^2 - y^2 + z^2)^2$$

The reference for this is Dickson's "*History of the Theory of Numbers*" though I've forgotten the specific page. This equivalence used to be in the Wikipedia article on [Descartes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem), but someone deleted it. There are parametric solutions to $(1)$.

---

**Solution 1**

If $a+b = c$ and $d = 2t$, then the equation simplifies as,

$$a^2+ab+b^2 = t^2$$

which is the same condition as in Tomita's answer.

**Solution 2**

If we prefer $a+b \neq c$, then there is also a parametrization using, perhaps not surprisingly, *Pythagorean triples*. Let,

$$(v,\,x,\,y,\,z) = \big(a e - b d,\, (a - d) (a + d),\, a(c + f),\, d(c + f)\big)$$

But we must first solve the pair,

$$a^2+b^2 =c^2\\
\,d^2+e^2 = f^2\\
\qquad ab = de$$

a simple solution of which is,

$$\big(a,b,c,d,e,f\big) = \big(u^2-v^2,\, 2uv,\, u^2+v^2,\, u^2-w^2,\, 2uw,\, u^2+w^2\big)$$

where $(u,v,w)$ obey the equation,

$$v^2+vw+w^2 = u^2$$

the same condition as Solution 1 (with different variables).

---

**P.S.** A quick search of,

$$\frac{(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2} {a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + d^4} = N$$

with $a<b<c<d<100$ yields no other integer $N$ except $N=2,3$ which seems to confirm David's comment (at least within that limited range).

Comment: So for the equation:(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2=n(a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4) we have numerical solutions, from Tito Piezas & Seiji Tomita's answers as follows. For n=2, (a,b,c,d)=(172,1024,5280,3168) & for n=3, (a,b,c,d)=(3,5,8,7). I don't think there are numerical solutions for (n=1,4,5,----)

Comment: @David A smaller solution for $n=2$ is $(a,b,c,d) = (3,5,8,14)$ while for $n=3$ is your $(a,b,c,d) = (3,5,8,7)$. There is a reason for the similarity of numbers, see my updated answer above. Also, I checked that at least for $a<b<c<d<100$, then it yields only $n=2,3$ and no other integers.

Comment: Piezas. Thanks for doing the numerical search for [a<b<c<d<100]. Actually there is a reference in Dickson book, to the identity mentioned by "OP". For (n=2), It is on page 659, Volume (2),chapter 22. Your two parametric solutions are more simple than that given in the book. The solution given is: For 
(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2=2(a,b,c,d)^4 is:[(a,b,c,d)]=[(4at),(3a^2+2at-t^2),(3a^2-2at-t^2),(6a^2+2t^2)]. And
for, (a,t)=(1,2), we get: (a,b,c,d)=(3,5,8,14).

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Thanks for the outstanding answer. Well, thinking about it, surely it's not possible to have $n>4$, because by Cauchy–Schwarz inequality (or Titu's lemma) $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2 \leq 4 * (a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4)$. Moreover, for $n=4$ iff $a=b=c=d$. $n=1$ is impossible too, thus for distinct solutions the only possible values ​​are $n=2, \,3$

Comment: @Falcon I see, and that is good to know. Anyway, protocol of this site is you should accept one of the answers so the question willl go out of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 4):

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2=3(a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4)$$
Let assume $c=a+b,$  then we get
$$a^2+ab+b^2=d^2$$
A parametric solution is given
$$(a,b,c,d)=(p^2-q^2, 2pq+q^2, p^2+2pq, q^2+pq+p^2)$$ where $p,q$ are any integer.